# I pressed the wrong shortcut key, now half my image is grey

Tags: adobe-photoshop

[image]Hi people,

I pressed a wrong set of shortcut keys (Shift ctrl z I think) now my image is half grey,

Can someone explain how to undo this

EDIT, please see below before after images, It seems to also scale the image
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You pressed <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Y</kbd> on Mac or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Y</kbd> on Win wich is the Gamut Warning

[image]

Press it again to disable it

Comment: Thanks, tried but that doesn't seem to work. Strangly, when pasting something, it seems to scale the image?? I'll attach a file showing the end effect